# GKE v1.1.1 KubernetesSeedProvider NullPointerException

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Cassandra image that worked with a GKE cluster v1.0.7 but has occassional issues starting on a new GKE cluster at v1.1.1 (no changes to the image or how it is created with kubectl just pointing to a new cluster).

I am using kubernetes-cassandra.jar from the kubernetes Cassandra example on github.

I see the following in kubectl logs.

```
INFO  21:57:01 Getting endpoints from https://kubernetes.default.cluster.local/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/cassandra
ERROR 21:57:01 Fatal error during configuration loading
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at io.k8s.cassandra.KubernetesSeedProvider.getSeeds(KubernetesSeedProvider.java:129) ~[kubernetes-cassandra.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:659) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:168) [apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:562) [apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:651) [apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
null
Fatal error during configuration loading; unable to start. See log for stacktrace.


$ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra                    0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   8          13m
```

Has anyone seen this error or have ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Seeing the same thing on AWS with the cassandra v1.1.1 example.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when service endpoint is not ready. To verify that, please check output of `kubectl get endpoints` against Cassandra service. If it is blank, then it means `KubernetesSeedProvider` is not able to deserialize the output received from Kubernetes API server as the endpoint's address is in `notReadyAddresses` state.

One possible work-around to this problem is to create a Cassandra pod before creating Cassandra service.